# How to implement pinch to zoom for this code

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, pinchzoom

I am developing a app with some photos.In this app i am trying to implement the pinch to zoom activity. I don't know how to do.I am searching for more than one week for this examples and there is no any example for implementing pinch to zoom in `ViewPager`. Here is my code. please help me to implement this and sorry for my English. here al1, al2 al3, all are the images in drawable folder.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPageAndroid);
    AndroidImageAdapter adapterView = new AndroidImageAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapterView);


}




private class AndroidImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    AndroidImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sliderImagesId.length;
    }
    private int[] sliderImagesId = new int[]{
            R.drawable.al1, R.drawable.al2, R.drawable.al3,
            R.drawable.al4, R.drawable.al5, R.drawable.al6,
            R.drawable.al7, R.drawable.al8,
    };

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
        return v == ((ImageView) obj);
    } @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
        ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
        return mImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, Object obj) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) obj);
    }}
```

}

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPageAndroid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/aa"
    />
```

Comment: you have to apply zoom on `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class from [HERE](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)
After implementing this class use `TouchImageView` instead of `ImageView` in your view pager like this:

```
   @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object obj) {
        return v == ((TouchImageView ) obj);
    } @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int i) {
        TouchImageView mImageView = new TouchImageView(mContext);
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        mImageView.setImageResource(sliderImagesId[i]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageView, 0);
        return mImageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int i, Object obj) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((TouchImageView) obj);
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

     public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
         super(context);
     }

     public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         super(context, attrs);
     }

     public interface ZoomViewListener {

         void onZoomStarted(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

         void onZooming(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);

         void onZoomEnded(float zoom, float zoomx, float zoomy);
     }

     // zooming
     float zoom = 1.0f;
     float maxZoom = 2.0f;
     float smoothZoom = 1.0f;
     float zoomX, zoomY;
     float smoothZoomX, smoothZoomY;
     private boolean scrolling; // NOPMD by karooolek on 29.06.11 11:45

     // minimap variables
     private boolean showMinimap = false;
     private int miniMapColor = Color.BLACK;
     private int miniMapHeight = -1;
     private String miniMapCaption;
     private float miniMapCaptionSize = 10.0f;
     private int miniMapCaptionColor = Color.WHITE;

     // touching variables
     private long lastTapTime;
     private float touchStartX, touchStartY;
     private float touchLastX, touchLastY;
     private float startd;
     private boolean pinching;
     private float lastd;
     private float lastdx1, lastdy1;
     private float lastdx2, lastdy2;

     // drawing
     private final Matrix m = new Matrix();
     private final Paint p = new Paint();

     // listener
     ZoomViewListener listener;

     private Bitmap ch;

     public float getZoom() {
         return zoom;
     }

     public float getMaxZoom() {
         return maxZoom;
     }

     public void setMaxZoom(final float maxZoom) {
         if (maxZoom < 1.0f) {
             return;
         }

         this.maxZoom = maxZoom;
     }

     public void setMiniMapEnabled(final boolean showMiniMap) {
         this.showMinimap = showMiniMap;
     }

     public boolean isMiniMapEnabled() {
         return showMinimap;
     }

     public void setMiniMapHeight(final int miniMapHeight) {
         if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
             return;
         }
         this.miniMapHeight = miniMapHeight;
     }

     public int getMiniMapHeight() {
         return miniMapHeight;
     }

     public void setMiniMapColor(final int color) {
         miniMapColor = color;
     }

     public int getMiniMapColor() {
         return miniMapColor;
     }

     public String getMiniMapCaption() {
         return miniMapCaption;
     }

     public void setMiniMapCaption(final String miniMapCaption) {
         this.miniMapCaption = miniMapCaption;
     }

     public float getMiniMapCaptionSize() {
         return miniMapCaptionSize;
     }

     public void setMiniMapCaptionSize(final float size) {
         miniMapCaptionSize = size;
     }

     public int getMiniMapCaptionColor() {
         return miniMapCaptionColor;
     }

     public void setMiniMapCaptionColor(final int color) {
         miniMapCaptionColor = color;
     }

     public void zoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
         this.zoom = Math.min(zoom, maxZoom);
         zoomX = x;
         zoomY = y;
         smoothZoomTo(this.zoom, x, y);
     }

     public void smoothZoomTo(final float zoom, final float x, final float y) {
         smoothZoom = clamp(1.0f, zoom, maxZoom);
         smoothZoomX = x;
         smoothZoomY = y;
         if (listener != null) {
             listener.onZoomStarted(smoothZoom, x, y);
         }
     }

     public ZoomViewListener getListener() {
         return listener;
     }

     public void setListner(final ZoomViewListener listener) {
         this.listener = listener;
     }

     public float getZoomFocusX() {
         return zoomX * zoom;
     }

     public float getZoomFocusY() {
         return zoomY * zoom;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
         // single touch
         if (ev.getPointerCount() == 1) {
             processSingleTouchEvent(ev);
         }

         // // double touch
         if (ev.getPointerCount() == 2) {
             processDoubleTouchEvent(ev);
         }

         // redraw
         getRootView().invalidate();
         invalidate();

         return true;
     }

     private void processSingleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {

         final float x = ev.getX();
         final float y = ev.getY();

         final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
         final float h = miniMapHeight;
         final boolean touchingMiniMap = x >= 10.0f && x <= 10.0f + w && y >= 10.0f && y <= 10.0f + h;

         if (showMinimap && smoothZoom > 1.0f && touchingMiniMap) {
             processSingleTouchOnMinimap(ev);
         } else {
             processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(ev);
         }
     }

     private void processSingleTouchOnMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
         final float x = ev.getX();
         final float y = ev.getY();

         final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
         final float h = miniMapHeight;
         final float zx = (x - 10.0f) / w * getWidth();
         final float zy = (y - 10.0f) / h * getHeight();
         smoothZoomTo(smoothZoom, zx, zy);
     }

     private void processSingleTouchOutsideMinimap(final MotionEvent ev) {
         final float x = ev.getX();
         final float y = ev.getY();
         float lx = x - touchStartX;
         float ly = y - touchStartY;
         final float l = (float) Math.hypot(lx, ly);
         float dx = x - touchLastX;
         float dy = y - touchLastY;
         touchLastX = x;
         touchLastY = y;

         switch (ev.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 touchStartX = x;
                 touchStartY = y;
                 touchLastX = x;
                 touchLastY = y;
                 dx = 0;
                 dy = 0;
                 lx = 0;
                 ly = 0;
                 scrolling = false;
                 break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 if (scrolling || (smoothZoom > 1.0f && l > 30.0f)) {
                     if (!scrolling) {
                         scrolling = true;
                         ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                         super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                     }
                     smoothZoomX -= dx / zoom;
                     smoothZoomY -= dy / zoom;
                     return;
                 }
                 break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                 // tap
                 if (l < 30.0f) {
                     // check double tap
                     if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTapTime < 500) {
                         if (smoothZoom == 1.0f) {
                             smoothZoomTo(maxZoom, x, y);
                         } else {
                             smoothZoomTo(1.0f, getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f);
                         }
                         lastTapTime = 0;
                         ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                         super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
                         return;
                     }

                     lastTapTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                     performClick();
                 }
                 break;

             default:
                 break;
         }

         ev.setLocation(zoomX + (x - 0.5f * getWidth()) / zoom, zoomY + (y - 0.5f * getHeight()) / zoom);

         ev.getX();
         ev.getY();

         super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
     }

     private void processDoubleTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
         final float x1 = ev.getX(0);
         final float dx1 = x1 - lastdx1;
         lastdx1 = x1;
         final float y1 = ev.getY(0);
         final float dy1 = y1 - lastdy1;
         lastdy1 = y1;
         final float x2 = ev.getX(1);
         final float dx2 = x2 - lastdx2;
         lastdx2 = x2;
         final float y2 = ev.getY(1);
         final float dy2 = y2 - lastdy2;
         lastdy2 = y2;

         // pointers distance
         final float d = (float) Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
         final float dd = d - lastd;
         lastd = d;
         final float ld = Math.abs(d - startd);

         Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
         switch (ev.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                 startd = d;
                 pinching = false;
                 break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                 if (pinching || ld > 30.0f) {
                     pinching = true;
                     final float dxk = 0.5f * (dx1 + dx2);
                     final float dyk = 0.5f * (dy1 + dy2);
                     smoothZoomTo(Math.max(1.0f, zoom * d / (d - dd)), zoomX - dxk / zoom, zoomY - dyk / zoom);
                 }

                 break;

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
             default:
                 pinching = false;
                 break;
         }

         ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
         super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
     }

     private float clamp(final float min, final float value, final float max) {
         return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
     }

     private float lerp(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
         return a + (b - a) * k;
     }

     private float bias(final float a, final float b, final float k) {
         return Math.abs(b - a) >= k ? a + k * Math.signum(b - a) : b;
     }

     @Override
     protected void dispatchDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
         // do zoom
         zoom = lerp(bias(zoom, smoothZoom, 0.05f), smoothZoom, 0.2f);
         smoothZoomX = clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / smoothZoom);
         smoothZoomY = clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom, smoothZoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / smoothZoom);

         zoomX = lerp(bias(zoomX, smoothZoomX, 0.1f), smoothZoomX, 0.35f);
         zoomY = lerp(bias(zoomY, smoothZoomY, 0.1f), smoothZoomY, 0.35f);
         if (zoom != smoothZoom && listener != null) {
             listener.onZooming(zoom, zoomX, zoomY);
         }

         final boolean animating = Math.abs(zoom - smoothZoom) > 0.0000001f
                 || Math.abs(zoomX - smoothZoomX) > 0.0000001f || Math.abs(zoomY - smoothZoomY) > 0.0000001f;

         // nothing to draw
         if (getChildCount() == 0) {
             return;
         }

         // prepare matrix
         m.setTranslate(0.5f * getWidth(), 0.5f * getHeight());
         m.preScale(zoom, zoom);
         m.preTranslate(-clamp(0.5f * getWidth() / zoom, zoomX, getWidth() - 0.5f * getWidth() / zoom),
                 -clamp(0.5f * getHeight() / zoom, zoomY, getHeight() - 0.5f * getHeight() / zoom));

         // get view
         final View v = getChildAt(0);
         m.preTranslate(v.getLeft(), v.getTop());

         // get drawing cache if available
         if (animating && ch == null && isAnimationCacheEnabled()) {
             v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             ch = v.getDrawingCache();
         }

         // draw using cache while animating
         if (animating && isAnimationCacheEnabled() && ch != null) {
             p.setColor(0xffffffff);
             canvas.drawBitmap(ch, m, p);
         } else { // zoomed or cache unavailable
             ch = null;
             canvas.save();
             canvas.concat(m);
             v.draw(canvas);
             canvas.restore();
         }

         // draw minimap
         if (showMinimap) {
             if (miniMapHeight < 0) {
                 miniMapHeight = getHeight() / 4;
             }

             canvas.translate(10.0f, 10.0f);

             p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
             final float w = miniMapHeight * (float) getWidth() / getHeight();
             final float h = miniMapHeight;
             canvas.drawRect(0.0f, 0.0f, w, h, p);

             if (miniMapCaption != null && miniMapCaption.length() > 0) {
                 p.setTextSize(miniMapCaptionSize);
                 p.setColor(miniMapCaptionColor);
                 p.setAntiAlias(true);
                 canvas.drawText(miniMapCaption, 10.0f, 10.0f + miniMapCaptionSize, p);
                 p.setAntiAlias(false);
             }

             p.setColor(0x80000000 | 0x00ffffff & miniMapColor);
             final float dx = w * zoomX / getWidth();
             final float dy = h * zoomY / getHeight();
             canvas.drawRect(dx - 0.5f * w / zoom, dy - 0.5f * h / zoom, dx + 0.5f * w / zoom, dy + 0.5f * h / zoom, p);

             canvas.translate(-10.0f, -10.0f);
         }

         // redraw
         // if (animating) {
         getRootView().invalidate();
         invalidate();
         // }
     }
 }
```

and replace this

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPageAndroid"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/aa"
/>
```

to

```
<com.example.demo.CustomViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewPageAndroid"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/aa"
/>
```